# Create a UITableView based on custom cell

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

I have a problem.
I want my table displays my custom cell. Each cell contains a button (see the attached file)

[image]

In the method cellForRowAtIndexPath I return the custom cell. The custom cell contains a UIButton as shown in attached image.

My problem is as follow - when i pressed the button it should light up (to red color) and other button should be attenuate (to blue color). How to make a connection between objects?

I would be happy with any answers! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

This my implementation of the UITableViewController class.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.delegate = self;
    [cells addObject:cell];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

- (void)mustDeselectWithout:(CustomCell *)cell{
    for (CustomCell * currentCell in cells) {
        if(currentCell != cell){
            [currentCell deselect];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see when I create cells I return custom cell in method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

This is class of the custom cell

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ProtocolCell.h"

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIButton * button;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<ProtocolCell> delegate;
- (void)select;
- (void)deselect;
@end
```

and .m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"


@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 25, 25)];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(select) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)select{
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [delegate mustDeselectWithout:self];
}

- (void)deselect{
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];    
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

My class UITableViewController implements protocol **ProtocolCell**. When I tap on the button my delegate call the method **mustDeselectWithout** and deselect all button in my array without current button.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class CustomCell;

@protocol ProtocolCell <NSObject>
- (void)mustDeselectWithout:(CustomCell *)cell;
@end
```

This is my implementation. If you could make comments I will be happy. Because I don know this is correct solution of the my problem or not. Thanks!